# Auto scroll on focus of a dynamic flex form

Tags: apache-flex, scroll, focus

First off here is the portion of .mxml that I am working with.

```
<s:Scroller id="scroller">
    <s:VGroup id="vGrp" >
        <mx:Form id="form"/>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Scroller>
```

I need the form to auto scroll based on the focused FormItem child that has focus. I have looked at [this](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/11/02/auto-scrolling-the-contents-of-a-vgroup-container-in-flex-4/) and tried this method. The issue that I am having is that my form is dynamically populated with FormItems. The example that I liked looks to only take into account that focusing will only happen to children of the VGroup. For me this is not the case and implementing the functions laid out in the linked website did not work for me (even after I did try to modify it to my particular case I was unable to get the scrolling to work properly). Any help would be much appreciated.